# How to remove an element from all lists in a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose I have a list of lists.

```
L = [[1,2,3], ['a',2,True],[1,44,33,12.1,90,2]]
```

I want to be able to remove all instances of a specific element from each of the sublists in the list L.

So for instance I might want to remove the number 2 so this would produce

```
L = [[1,3], ['a',True],[1,44,33,12.1,90]]
```

I tried to use this function + code:

```
def remove_values_from_list(the_list, val):
    return [value for value in the_list if value != val]

for i in L:
    i = remove_values_from_list(i, '2')
```

However the output still gives L in its original form and doesn't remove the 2.

Comment: `i = remove_values_from_list(i, '2')` you overwrite i with the return of the function ???

Answer (score 5):

`i` is a variable that is not connected to `L`. It is assigned a value from `L`, then you reassign it to something else; this will not affect `L` at all.

A non-destructive way to do this (i.e. preserve `L`, make a new list for the result):

```
newL = [[value for value in the_list if value != val] for the_list in L]
```

A destructive way (i.e. change `L` itself):

```
for the_list in L:
    while value in the_list:
        the_list.remove(value)
```

Comment: Does this for loop go inside the function then?

Comment: Those are both complete solutions. If you want to make them into functions, the first one would accept `L` and return `newL`, while the second woild accept `L` and have no `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def remove_values_from_list(the_list, val):
    return [[v for v in l1 if v!= val] for l1 in the_list]
```

In your code, you were checking whether only one sub-list is equivalent to the the `val` parameter. You need to check it inside sub-lists. Also a secondary mistake would be to check items inside sub-lists with exact type. You are searching for `'2'` (str type) where as there is `2` (int type) in the sub-lists.